# Unable to add index to foreign key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add an index to a foreign key in Rails:

```
add_index :reports, :unit_id
```

Unfortunately, it gives me the below error:

```
==  AddIndexToReportsUnitId: migrating ========================================
-- add_index(:reports, :unit_id)
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::Error: ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
: 
           SELECT distinct i.relname, d.indisunique, d.indkey, pg_get_indexdef(d.indexrelid), t.oid,
                  m.amname, pg_get_expr(d.indpred, t.oid), pg_get_expr(d.indexprs, t.oid)
           FROM pg_class t
           INNER JOIN pg_index d ON t.oid = d.indrelid
           INNER JOIN pg_class i ON d.indexrelid = i.oid
           INNER JOIN pg_am m ON i.relam = m.oid
           WHERE i.relkind = 'i'
             AND d.indisprimary = 'f'
             AND t.relname = 'reports'
             AND i.relnamespace IN (SELECT oid FROM pg_namespace WHERE nspname = ANY (current_schemas(false)) )
          ORDER BY i.relname
```

Any idea why this is happening? It only happens when I try to add an index to this specific column. I was able to add an index to another column.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I understand why it happened. I had already had an index on that column:

```
\d + reports
...
"index_reports_on_unit_id" btree (unit_id)
```

Wow, I wish it gave me a better hint when it raised the exception.